# How do you display a QChartView in a Custom Widget?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a QChart that I've assigned to a QChartView. In the example I've been following the chart is displayed, in main.cpp, as:

```
window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
```

In my project I want to utilize the designer and as such have created a custom widget, but it's not displaying the QChart. I found an example where they assigned they assigned the view to a layout and then set the layout, as such:

```
mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
mainLayout->addWidget(chartView, 0, 0);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

But this seems to mess with the layout of all the other widgets within the window. How do I get the Custom Widget to display my chartView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the class inherit from QChartView (which inherits QWidget) instead of QWidget, then did:

```
setChart(myChart);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it.

In your .h file:

```
QGridLayout* gridLayot;
QChart *chart;
QChartView *chartView;
```

in your .cpp file in the main constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow){    
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
this->setCentralWidget(ui->centralWidget);    

chart  = new QChart;
chartView = new QChartView(chart);
gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
gridLayout->addWidget(chartView,0,0);
```

Anytime you want to change the chart I do this:

```
chart  = new QChart;
chartView = new QChartView(chart);
gridLayout->addWidget(chartView,0,0);
```